# Nginx forward from domain A port 8080 to domain B port 80

Tags: redirect, nginx

Currently I'm able to do required redirrects from server A to server B, both listening port 80 default / location.

What I need is additional forward of all requests sent to server A port 8080 non-default location /loc1 to Server B port 80 (the same) location /loc1

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 1.1.1.1;
    return 301 $scheme://1.1.1.2$request_uri;
}
```

Is this only doable by adding additional server section like below?

Edit:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 1.1.1.1;

    location /loc1 {
        return 301 $scheme://1.1.1.2:80$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Having two above "server" sections in config worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need an additional server block to listen on 8080. In the second config you've provided, I think there's a typo. `8080` shouldn't be in `server_name`. Also, having the return statement there means that **all** requests to `1.1.1.1:8080` will get redirected to `1.1.1.2:80`. If you only want to redirect if `/loc1` is in the URI, then add a location block as seen below:

```
server{
       listen 8080;
       server_name 1.1.1.1;

       #rest of your config

       location /loc1 {
           return 301 $scheme://1.1.1.2:80$request_uri;
       }
 }
```